# HTML Login form with PHP Authentication

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Here is an image of the output we are currently getting

[image]

Trying to create a login form in html, sent to an authentication file in PHP to direct to the website welcome page. The error we are getting is included in the image attached. Help please.

This is a seperate php file for the authentication

```
<?php
    include_once('db.php');
    //if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        session_start();
        $login = $_POST['txtUsername'];
        $pass = $_POST['txtPassword'];

    //check if login exists
    $sql1 = "SELECT * from DriverRegistration WHERE Username = '$login' AND Password = '$pass';";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    $r1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
    echo $sql1;
    echo $result1;
    echo $r1;
    // if there is a matching User with the username/email
    if($r1 == 1){
    // fetch row info from query
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

    $_SESSION["username"] = $res["Username"];
    $_SESSION["driveID"] = $res["DriverID"];

    header("Location: welcome.html");
    }else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Incorrect Password"); </script>';
    }

    ?>
```

This is a seperate html file for the login page

```
 <HTML>
    <Head>
    <title>Catch A Ride: Login</title>
    </Head>
    <Form name="Login" method="post" action="authentication.php">



<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<CENTER><Table>
<TR>
    <TD colspan=2> <img src = "Catcharide.png" alt = "Company Logo"width = 250 height = 200>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD> Username:
    <TD> <input type="text" name="txtUsername" size="20">
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD> Password:
    <TD> <input type="text" name="txtPassword" size="20"> 
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD colspan=3> <br> <center> <input type="submit" value="Login"> </center><br>
    </TD>

</TR>
<TR>
    <TD colspan=2> <Center>Need to Register? <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="location.href='registrationDriver.html';"</A>
</TR>
</Table>
</Form>
</Body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What is the error? I see a success message

Comment: There is no error in your code.

Comment: Why is it not redirecting me to the welcome page?

Comment: You cannot `echo` anything before a header